# Can The VSO WIT templates be customized?

Tags: azure-devops, tfsbuild

I want to add fields to the Bugs template on the Visual Studio Online, can it be done?

I've briefly read these articles but I'm still not sure if the templates on Visual Studio Online can be exported, edited and imported with the witadmin tool

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh409273.aspx 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj920163.aspx  https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd312129.aspx

Comment: What sort of customizations do you want?

Comment: Additional fields in Bugs and PBIs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not currently possible to customise the VSO process templates.

It is listed as a future feature but with no timeline...

Comment: No announced timeline, but it's not too far out in the future. :-)